# Trouble with implicit user-defined conversions

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I have two classes: `CoolEnum`, which is an attempt to turn `enum class` into a real class with methods; `template <class WrapMe> class Wrapper;`, which is implicitly convertible to `const WrapMe&`

I've come up with the following implementation:

```
#include <cassert>

class CoolEnum {
public:
    enum Impl {
        kFirst, kSecond
    };

    explicit CoolEnum(Impl value) : value_(value) {
    }

    operator Impl() const {
        return value_;
    }

    CoolEnum Inverse() const {
        switch (value_) {
            case kFirst:
                return CoolEnum{kSecond};
            default:
                return CoolEnum{kFirst};
        }
    }

private:
    Impl value_;
};

template <class WrapMe>
class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper(WrapMe value, char other_info)
        : value_(value), other_info_(other_info) {
    }

    operator const WrapMe&() const {
        return value_;
    }

private:
    WrapMe value_;
    char other_info_;
};

int main() {
    // compiles
    assert(CoolEnum(CoolEnum::kFirst) == CoolEnum::kFirst);

    // does not compile: no match for operator ==
    assert(CoolEnum(CoolEnum::kFirst)
       == Wrapper<CoolEnum>(CoolEnum(CoolEnum::kFirst), 'e'));
    return 0;
}
```

I surely can just `static_cast` `Wrapper<CoolEnum>` to `CoolEnum`, but I believe that it might be possible to fix `CoolEnum` class and avoid it.

One of the solutions I know of is to remove `operator Impl` from `CoolEnum`, and I guess its because it results in ambiguity (though I don't fully understand why). To elaborate, I believe there are several possibilities for `operator ==`:

1. convert `Wrapper` to `CoolEnum` and compare
2. convert `Wrapper` to `Impl` and compare
3. ... (maybe others)

but it seems like it should trivially be allowed -- all of them are compiler-generated, and lead to the same result

I have two questions:

1. Why exactly do I get a compilation error?
2. What is the best possible fix for `CoolEnum` class?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the `operator==` definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why exactly do I get a compilation error?

You are only allowed one user defined conversion in a conversion sequence.  When you do

```
CoolEnum(CoolEnum::kFirst) == Wrapper<CoolEnum>(CoolEnum(CoolEnum::kFirst)
```

`CoolEnum(CoolEnum::kFirst)` can be converted to a `CoolEnum::Impl` in a single step but `Wrapper<CoolEnum>(CoolEnum(CoolEnum::kFirst)` first has to convert the `Wrapper` to a `CoolEnum`, and then convert that to a `CoolEnum::Impl`.  Since that is two user defined conversions you get an error

> What is the best possible fix for CoolEnum class?

Just add a `operator ==` for it.  You can then do the comparison of the enum value in there.  This will work because it only take a single user defined conversion to go from a `Wrapper<T>` to `T`.  Changing the code to

```
#include <cassert>

class CoolEnum {
public:
    enum Impl {
        kFirst, kSecond
    };

    explicit CoolEnum(Impl value) : value_(value) {
    }

    operator Impl() const {
        return value_;
    }

    CoolEnum Inverse() const {
        switch (value_) {
            case kFirst:
                return CoolEnum{kSecond};
            default:
                return CoolEnum{kFirst};
        }
    }
    friend bool operator ==(const CoolEnum& lhs, const CoolEnum& rhs);
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ added this ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

private:
    Impl value_;
};

bool operator ==(const CoolEnum& lhs, const CoolEnum& rhs)
{
    return lhs.value_ == rhs.value_;
}
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ added this ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

template <class WrapMe>
class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper(WrapMe value, char other_info)
        : value_(value), other_info_(other_info) {
    }

    operator const WrapMe&() const {
        return value_;
    }

private:
    WrapMe value_;
    char other_info_;
};

int main() {
    // compiles
    assert(CoolEnum(CoolEnum::kFirst) == CoolEnum::kFirst);

    // does not compile: no match for operator ==
    assert(CoolEnum(CoolEnum::kFirst)
       == Wrapper<CoolEnum>(CoolEnum(CoolEnum::kFirst), 'e'));
    return 0;
}
```

lets it compile

Comment: "You are only allowed one user defined conversion in a conversion sequence"

Thanks for clarifying! That's exactly the answer I was looking for